# What is the opposite of attr_accessible in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

What is the opposite of attr_accessible in Rails?

Instead of writting every single attribute I want to write just the ones I want to block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[attr_protected](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_protected)

> Mass-assignment to these attributes will simply be ignored, to assign to them you can use direct writer methods. This is meant to protect sensitive attributes from being overwritten by malicious users tampering with URLs or forms.

Comment: This is correct. Of course, please do be careful to consider whether to add new attributes to the attr_protected list when adding any attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Its attr_protected, information can be found here...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_protected